# Exercise of weak convergence

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This is an exercise of Central Limit Theorem (CLT):

> Let $(X_j)_{j\geq 1}$ be i.i.d. with $E[X_1]=1$ and $\sigma_{X_1}^2=\sigma^2\in(0,\infty)$($\sigma>0$). Show that
>   $$
> \frac{2}{\sigma}(\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n})\to Z
> $$
>   in distribution with $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

What I think is that 
$$
\frac{S_n-n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\to Z
$$
in distribution, which is the CLT. We also have
$$
\frac{S_n-n}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}=\frac{2(\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n})}{\sigma}\frac{(\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt{n})}{2\sqrt{n}}. 
$$
Then it suffices to show that 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}\to 1
$$
in probability. How can I go on?

Comment: Presumably one needs to add the hypothesis that $X_1\geqslant0$ with full probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we need to show that $\frac{S_n}n$ converges in probability to $1$. As $t\mapsto \sqrt t$ is continuous, it follows from the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\frac{\sqrt{S_n} + \sqrt{n}}{2 \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \sqrt{\frac{S_n}{n}}\right)$. What can you say about the limit of $\frac{S_n}{n}$ ?